# Cosa significa "rappattare"?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel racconto *Un giorno di fuoco*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Dopo, ritrovai lui davanti a casa, calmo come se non avessero affatto litigato o l’**avessero** alla fine **rappattata** benissimo; si stuzzicava i denti con uno zolfanello usato.

La mia domanda è sul significato del verbo "rappattare" che appare in questa frase. Non ho trovato questo vocabolo in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Mi sembra però che si tratti di un derivato di "patto". Si tratta forse di una variante regionale di "[pattuire](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pattuire)"?

Comment: Direi “fare patta”, cioè parità.

Comment: Nel [Tommaseo-Bellini](http://www.tommaseobellini.it/#/doc) si trova "pattare" e "rappattumare" col significato di "rappacificare" o "rappacificarsi", ma non "rappattare" (l'ho scoperto cercando "patta" come suggerito da @egreg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In questo dizionario per [rappattare](https://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?lemma=RAPPATTARE100) ho trovato:

> **rappattàre**   
>   rap|pat|tà|re 
>  pronuncia: /rappatˈtare/ 
>  *verbo transitivo*
>
> 1 *arcaico* di una lite, un diverbio, una contesa: comporre, appianare,
>   rappacificare
>
> 2 *arcaico* detto di un'amicizia: ricucire facendo pace

Nel contesto da te citato significa che i litiganti si erano riappacificati come se non vi fosse stato nessun litigio.

Comment: Veramente, il significato sembra questo. La cosa strana è che non si trovi in nessun altro dizionario.